# Verify a method was called from another object OCMock

Tags: objective-c, testing, mocking, stub, ocmock

I have two classes.

Object 1:

```
- (void) methodA {
    ObjectB objectB = [[ObjectB alloc] init];
    [objectB methodB];
}
```

And Object 2:

```
- (void) methodB {
     // Does something
}
```

Using OCMock, how do I verify that `methodA` calls `methodB`? I'm setting the test up like the following:

```
id mock = OCMClassMock([Object2 class]);
OCMStub([mock methodB).andReturn(nil);

[self.object1 methodA];
OCMVerify([mock methodB]);
```

The test class is testing object1, but I'd like to verify that it calls the method on object2. When running this test, I get the failing message:

```
Method methodB was not invoked.
```

I'm still really new to mocks/stubs. It's entirely possible that I'm structuring the test wrong. The mock confuses me a little because I'm testing `Object1`, but trying to verify something on `Object2`.

Am I thinking correctly when I am setting up this test? If not, how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure (somehow) that `Object1` uses the mock and not a fresh instance of `ObjectB`. The usual approach to do this is dependency injection, ie. Object1 has a dependency on Object2, but instead of Object1 creating an instance of Object2, the instance of Object2 is set from the outside (injected). There's a huge amount of stuff about it on the web.

With OCMock you could hack your way around this another way. This is not recommended, though. You could replace `alloc`/`init` with `new`, then stub the `new` class method to return the mock. That way Object1 would use the mock without even knowing it. It would still "think" that it allocated a fresh instance of Object2.

```
id mock = OCMClassMock([Object2 class]);
OCMStub([mock new]).andReturn(mock);
OCMStub([mock methodB).andReturn(nil);

[self.object1 methodA];
OCMVerify([mock methodB]);
```

This is mentioned in the reference documentation in 9.3. Stubbing methods that create objects.